# InfoPath 2007 edit forms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath

Is it possible to edit forms in SharePoint 2010 with InfoPath 2007? I only have 2007 installed on my machine and do not see a way to be able to edit the form for my custom list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot edit the list forms with InfoPath 2007. You would have to have InfoPath 2010, which supports list forms. 2007 does not.